# Problem with invalidate tags in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a problem with invalidating requests after login, which occurs after logout.
After login mutation I use onQueryStarted and await queryFilled. After that I dispatch api.util.invalidateTags and it doesn't work but it happens after logout where I resetApiState

```
// My store.ts file
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import { courcesApi } from "./services/courcesApi";
import { emptySplitApi } from "./services/emptySplitApi";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [emptySplitApi.reducerPath]: emptySplitApi.reducer,
    },

    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(emptySplitApi.middleware).concat(courcesApi.middleware),
})

setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

```
// emptySplitApi.ts
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';


export const emptySplitApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://camp-courses.api.kreosoft.space/', 
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (token) {
      headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    }

    return headers;
  } }),
  tagTypes: ['Profile', 'Groups', 'MyCources', 'TeachingCources'],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
})
```

```
// Here in loginUser I dispatch emptySplitApi.util.invalidateTags
export const accountApi = emptySplitApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (build) => ({
      getUserProfile: build.query<Profile, void>({
        query: () => '/profile',
        providesTags: ["Profile"]
      }),
      loginUser: build.mutation<{ token: string }, Login>({
        query(body: Login) {
            return {
                url: '/login',
                method: "POST",
                body,
            }
        },
        async onQueryStarted(_, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
          try {
            const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
            localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
            dispatch(emptySplitApi.util.invalidateTags(['Profile', 'Groups', 'MyCources', 'TeachingCources']));
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }),
      logoutUser: build.mutation<void, void>({
        query() {
            return {
                url: '/logout',
                method: "POST",
            }
        },
        async onQueryStarted(_, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
          try {
            await queryFulfilled;
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            dispatch(emptySplitApi.util.resetApiState());
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }),
      getUserRoles: build.query<RolesList, void>({
        query: () => '/roles',
      })
    }),
    overrideExisting: false,
  })
  
  export const { useGetUserProfileQuery, useLoginUserMutation, useLogoutUserMutation, useGetUserRolesQuery } = accountApi
```

When I haven't token in localStorage and go to the page on the first time. Then login invalidate works [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3l8Y.png)
But after I logout and login again, invalidate doesn't work
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pVWc.png)

Maybe logout have problems